# Anime where a girl is reborn as a baby on different worlds to find pieces of a crystal

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'm from Russia, I translated this text

My girlfriend told me many times about one rather interesting anime that she watched as a child. We tried for a long time to find it, but nothing came out.

She watched it when she was about 6-9 years old on a Russian TV channel. She herself was born in 98. The plot was quite simple, but very interesting.

It all started with a planet inhabited by something similar to humans, where a crystal collapses and it is scattered across billions of universes. The main character will have to collect it, for this she will be born as a baby in each world and looks for a piece of the crystal. The pieces could have been anywhere, so there were murders and so on. It was like a piece of crystal in a person's body made them superhuman. So, after finding a piece, she went to another world and so on in a circle. As time went on, she became more and more violent, she began to go mad. At the end of the anime, she did not remember who she was, what she needed, but she remembered only one thing, that she needed to find a piece of the crystal, so she immediately turned into an adult and immediately destroyed the world, so as not to delay with all this.

There's also the fact that the girl herself was originally not a person, but something like a spirit. And all the billions of worlds where she was, there were some types of people, someone with rabbit ears, tails and so on.

I tried to search in the lists of anime that were on TV, but it did not give a result. There is an option to search for TV shows of those years, but they are all in the newspaper version. But somehow my girlfriend found by chance 1 frame from the anime, the heroine herself, the drawing looks like Sailor Moon.

She then came across an article titled something like "forever lost anime", which described her anime and had the same frame. But it was a long time ago, maybe it was found.

Comment: Could you [edit] in the image you found of this? It would help a lot for others to find this for you?

Comment: At the moment, I do not have it, my girlfriend is looking for it now, I hope she will find it

Answer (score 2):

I think your girlfriend might have seen a few episodes of Sailor Moon's 5th and last season, [*"Sailor Moon Sailor Stars"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sailor_Moon_Sailor_Stars).

The series originally aired in Japan from 1996 to 1997, so she could have seen a later rerun.

The *"main character"* your friend remembers could be [Sailor Galaxia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Galactica#Sailor_Galaxia), actually the main villain of the season, whose backstory is shown as a flashback in one of the last episodes (if I remember correctly) and matches the *"going mad"* and *"looking for crystals"* parts of your description.

Sailor Galaxia, however, does not match the *"she will be born as a baby in each world"* part.

Comment: Yes, I know it's similar, but unfortunately not(